# Transaction hash when call extrinsic

Tags: polkadot-js, extrinsic

Is there any way I can get the state of the extrinsic when I initiate the call before the block is finalized?
Thanks

Comment: What you mean by state? Do you mean if the transaction is already included in a block or still waiting in the tx pool?

Comment: Tx still waiting in the tx pool. If tx transaction finalized, I can get via event.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I mean when I call an extrinsic, can I get extrinsic information
Currently, I can only get the extrinsic information after the block is finalized.

Answer (score 1):

it is in pending queue before finized, you may try some blockchain explorer like [subscan](https://kusama.subscan.io/extrinsic)

Comment: I want get in my node via api.query.